# Opacity on parent <View> is not applying properly to <Image> on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm having some weird rendering issue on Android. Here is my simple code:

```
<View style={{ opacity: 0.4, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 24 }}>
  <Image
    source={{ uri }}
    style={{ height: 56, width: 56, resizeMode: 'contain' }}
  />
</View>
```

Does anyone know of issues why opacity would affect the child image differently?

On Android it renders weird:

[image: android renders bad]

On iOS it renders fine, the opacity is consistent on child `<Image>`:

[image: ios renders good]

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this? I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: Not yet @BSimpson :( I'm also still looking :(

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if that's a bug but you can just add the `opacity: 0.4` to the style of the `Image` component

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too, but it doesn't look right either. :(